# IMPORTJSON won't update in Google Spreadsheets no matter what i do

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a spreadsheet that reads prices from Cryptsy,

But the values only update once, even though i have tried many solutions on SO.

I'm using

=ImportJSON("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=261&refresh=NOW()", "/return/markets/VIA/lasttradeprice",
                "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders",GOOGLECLOCK())

I also tried NOW() - which just hangs.

The sheet is set to refresh on every save and every minute.

I am using the script from

https://gist.github.com/chrislkeller/5719258

I honestly have no idea why it is not updating (i just opened it fresh this morning and the prices are still the same)

Help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Cryptsy API:

### General Market Data (Single Market - Realtime):

```
http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid={MARKET ID}
```

[Cryptsy Documentation for their API](https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/publicapi)

You are adding:

```
&refresh=NOW()
```

to the end of the URL for the HTTP Request.  I don't see any option for adding anything like that when I look that the Cryptsy documentation.

Instead of trying to trigger a HTTP Request from a spreadsheet function, you could try running a script, then have the script put the data into the spreadsheet.  Get a very basic script to run every minute, if that's what you want, and then build from there.  Just get a script to run every minute, and read up on urlFetch:

[URL Fetch Service - Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/)

Answer (score 0):

You are hardcoding "&refresh=now()" as a string inside the url. I suppose your intent was to generate a unique url every time so google wont cache the result.
try "yourUrl&refresh="+now() so the function `now` is outside the string and actually evaluates. Might only work in old sheets and not new sheets.